Are all square taper cartridge BB cups right hand threaded on the non drive side?
Asking because the BB won't budge. Secondly is there any important reason why it's often recommended to unfasten the NDS first? At least for the Shimano UN300 type I see no reason why this is critical, but I am asking since the BB in question is of unknown type and might have a design unkown to me.

What kind of frame is it?

@PaulH Merida, around 10years old, hybrid bike. Alu frame.

Turns out to be a FSA square taper unit, but still isn't budging.

Every threaded shell frame standard is right-hand threaded on the NDS. There's always weirdo fringe scenarios like it's a thread-together repair BB (for stripped shells) someone installed backwards, or someone insisted on jamming a normal BB into a frame the wrong direction (though in that case you'd probably notice that by the shoulder being on the wrong side).
The canned wisdom of undoing the NDS first is indeed overstated. It doesn't really matter on the removal end. When it's stuck, what you want to be doing is treat your tool fittings as a finite resource, because if they get destroyed that's when the trouble really starts. Don't do the same things over and over if it's not working. Find ways of using heat or cold (Finish Line Chill Zone is my big favorite for this and many other things - use a lot of it and let it sit a while).

Yep - the mechanic's job is to generally to save the frame much more than the cup/cartridge.

I thought there is an Italian "standard" which uses opposite thread direction?

Found it. ITA vs BSA https://www.bikeradar.com/features/what-is-the-difference-between-an-italian-and-bsa-bottom-bracket

@Michael ITA is right hand threaded on both sides IIRC. So it’s still true that the NDS is always right hand threaded.

@Criggie Yes, afraid the frame will crack before this one comes out, but perhaps some more time with anti-rust will solve it :\

@NathanKnutson probably good advice, but can't get new tools to save this ancient creature. Put some rust-remover down the seat-tube, but not sure it actually was an opening to the BB down there. Let it simmer for 36h, and now resting on the side for a sideways treatment. Thx for all advice anyway, hopefully usefull for someone in the future.

@WornChain There are options - I once fed a hacksaw blade through a BB hole (I got the other side out and then the axle and loose bearings) then I cut enough of a slot in the stuck cup for it to relax and come out.   A new cartridge went in okay, so I guess someone used red locktite.
